# this code keeps returning with Error:Unknown column 'NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH' in 'field list'

Tags: php

Here is my query :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `church_report` (
  `report_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  ` NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Date` date NOT NULL,
  `ADDRESS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `MEMBERS_PRESENT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_11` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_12` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_13` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_14` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_15` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ADULTS_16` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_ATTENDED` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_6` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_7` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_8` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_9` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_10` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_11` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_12` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_13` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CHILDREN_14` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ABSENTEES_AND_REASON` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DID_EVERY_MEMBER_DO_THEIR_DUTIES` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `If_No` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `WAS_THE_PROGRAMME_FOLLOWED` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `If_No_Why` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `WHAT_ITEM_OF_THE_PROGRAMME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `WHAT_ITEM_OF_THE_PROGRAMME_WAS_NOT` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RATE1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `RATE2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RATE3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RATE4` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `RATE5` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `IF_YOU_RATED_IN_FROM_1_3` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `V_I_P` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `A_PROFILE_OF_THE_V_I_P` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DID_YOU_CAST_THE_VISION` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `IF_NO_WHY_NOT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `IF_YES_HOW_DID_YOU_DO_IT` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `PASTORVILLAGE` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `OTHER_COMMENTS` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`report_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

$sql = "INSERT INTO church_report 
        (NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD, NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH, Date, ADDRESS, 
        ADULTS_1, ADULTS_2, ADULTS_3, ADULTS_4, ADULTS_5, ADULTS_6, 
        ADULTS_7, ADULTS_8, ADULTS_9, ADULTS_10, ADULTS_11, ADULTS_12, 
        ADULTS_13, ADULTS_14, ADULTS_15, ADULTS_16, CHILDREN1, CHILDREN2, 
        CHILDREN_3, CHILDREN_4, CHILDREN_5, CHILDREN_6, CHILDREN_7, 
        CHILDREN_8,CHILDREN_9, CHILDREN_10, CHILDREN_11, CHILDREN_12, 
        CHILDREN_13, CHILDREN_14, ABSENTEES_AND_REASON, DID_EVERY_MEMBER_DO_THEIR_DUTIES, 
        If_No, WAS_THE_PROGRAMME_FOLLOWED, If_No_Why, WHAT_ITEM_OF_THE_PROGRAMME, 
        WHAT_ITEM_OF_THE_PROGRAMME_WAS_NOT, RATE1, RATE2, RATE3, RATE4, RATE5, 
        IF_YOU_RATED_IN_FROM_1_3, V_I_P, A_PROFILE_OF_THE_V_I_P, DID_YOU_CAST_THE_VISION, 
        IF_NO_WHY_NOT, IF_YES_HOW_DID_YOU_DO_IT, PASTOR_VILLAGE, OTHER_COMMENTS)  

        VALUES ('value', 'value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value5', 'value6', 'value7',
        'value8', 'value9', 'value10','value11', 'value12', 'value13', 'value14', 
        'value15', 'value16', 'value17', 'value18', 'value19', 'value20','value22', 
        'value23', 'value24', 'value25', 'value26', 'value27', 'value28', 'value29', 
        'value30', 'value31', 'value32', 'value33', 'value34', 'value35', 'value36', 
        'value37', 'value38', 'value39', 'value40', 'value41', 'value42', 'value43', 
        'value44', 'value45', 'value46', 'value47', 'value48', 'value49', 'value50', 
        'value51', 'value52', 'value53', 'value54', 'value55')";  
        // $success = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: Make sure this column exist in your church_report table.

Comment: As the error states, there is no column `NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH` in your table.

Comment: HI it dose please see picture

Comment: I'm always looking in my refigerator for something to eat, but there's never any food in there. Turns out I have to put it there first, before I can find it. Code and databases are like that too, you can't query columns that aren't there.

Comment: Still eagerly awaiting on that picture....maybe better if you post your table schema, and your PHP code showing your SQL queries.

Comment: HI Guy I'm trying to add a picture to show

Comment: You have a space in `\` NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH\``, so the error is correct. Change to `\`NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH\``

Comment: And a possible typo in `NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD`

Comment: Thanks guys its sorted

Comment: @ JustBaron how do you do that

Comment: @Louie Click the `tick` next my answer...the `up` arrow up-votes the answer too ;)

Comment: This should really be closed as a typo since that's all it was in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL error is valid because you have a space in your table schema and therefore rendering your query incorrect:

```
`NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
` NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH` varchar(255) NOT NULL, <-- Here is the space!
`Date` date NOT NULL,
```

Change your table schema to:

```
`NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH` varchar(255) NOT NULL, <-- Space removed!
`Date` date NOT NULL,
```

or amend your SQL query to:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO church_report 
        (`NAME_OF_DEPUTY_SHERHERD`, ` NAME_OF_HOUSE_CHURCH`, ....
```

And as a side note, you will be advised to update your `mysql()` functions to at least `mysqli()` or `pdo` functions.